# Why does Ask Ubuntu need a Captcha even from mobile users?

Tags: feature-request, captcha

I am using my mobile phone to access Ask Ubuntu with Opera mini and it works with Ask Ubuntu mobile version but while posting answers it redirects me to the full website to enter a Captcha.

Why is there no mobile version?

Comment: Is the question regarding why mobile users need to answer a captcha, or why there is no mobile version of the captcha page?

Comment: why mobile user have to enter captcha,and why there is no mobile version for it?